# How to suspend a sourced script in bash?

Tags: bash, job-control

When I run a process in Bash, I can suspend it with Ctrl-Z, but that does not seem to work for sourced scripts (`. foo.sh`). Is there a way to suspend such scripts?

Answer (score 1):

When you source foo.sh, Ctrl+Z (SUSP) just stops the currently executing command **in** foo.sh and the shell blithely carries on with the next command in foo.sh.

I don't think there's a way round this. If you want to be able to suspend the whole of foo.sh you have to be running it as a subprocess by invoking it as a command not by sourcing it.

Comment: Indeed, Ctrl-Z suspends a **process** using SIGSTOP. Sourced scripts run in the main shell process and cannot be suspended as a unit.